# Plane cutting a Sphere

Tags: coordinates

I have a problem of geometry.
Suppose an half sphere of radius=1 rapresented in spherical coordinate

```
     x = sin(theta)cos(phi)
     y = sin(theta)sin(phi)
     z = cos(theta)
```

with

```
     0<phi<360° and 0<theta<90
```

in other word the sphere has only z>0.

Then consider a plane inclined respect to the z axis and passing for the x axis.

How can obtain the values of theta and phi intersection of the sphere whit the plane?

I'm able to obtain the expression of the plane like

```
     ax + by + cz + d = 0    (d=0)
```

but using the expressions of the x, y and z of the sphere, i did not find any solutions.

Could you help me?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I add the solution found.
Considering the angles phi between 0° e 180° (the other angles produce solution with z negative) and said phi0 one of these angles.

Replacing in the equation of the plane the expressions of the spherical coordinates of the sphere we have:

```
a sin(theta) cos(phi0) + b sin(Theta) sin(phi0) + C cos(theta) = 0
```

then

```
A = a cos(phi0);  B = b sin(phi0)
```

dividing this expression by cos(theta):

```
A tan(theta) + B tan(theta) + c = 0
```

The solution is:

```
theta = atan2(-c, A+B)
```

The atan2 produce directly the right value.